# PHP header does not redirect back to starting page

Tags: php, http-post

*([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) does not answer my question).*

I am trying to redirect to the landing page after a user attempts to login, here is what I've done:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if ($loginSuccess)
{
    echo "Logged in: True";
    header("Location: index.php?status=1", true, 200);
}
else
{
    echo "Logged in: False";
    header("Location: index.php?status=0", true, 401);
}
ob_end_flush();
exit();
?>
```

However when I try this I get the page never gets redirected back to the page that the request was made with (index.php)

[image]

Comment: A `Location` header _alone_ does not redirect, it needs to be accompanied by a 3xx status code. But what do we have here, according to your screenshot? `Status: 401`

Comment: Wow, so that was the problem? It worked with 308, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

try put this code before the `ob_start()`, becuase the header sometimes already called

```
ob_clean()
```

or change to javascript redirect using this if the `ob_clean()` not worked

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php?status=1'</script>";
```

Comment: Didn't work and I do not want to use JavaScript in my situation as I'm returning a JSON object in my actual code.